# Examples of jet turbine values for combustions, fuel flow, Q of fuel, temp of exhaust, etc. for classroom use

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, aircraft-physics, efficiency, combustion

I am trying to build jet turbine examples for a class and I want to use actual values for the mass flow of fuel and air, combustion temps, exhaust temps, exhaust composition (CO, CO2,H20,o2, NOx) ext…

I thought this would be a quick 20 minutes of googling but I cant seem to find a clean consolidated source for the information.

I want to have the students run multiple scenarios showing a lean mix lowers the adiabatic flame temp and produced less NOx vs older designs that ran rich and had higher emissions rates. The values don’t need to be 100% accurate but in the ballpark would be nice. Links to sources would be best. Generic values used commonly in industry as back of a napkin values are a start.

I see that there are a lot of questions in the same ballpark of this but I (from my first run through) did not see one with all the information. Sorry if this is a repeat there are 1000’s of Questions on here to sift through.

Comment: For [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/80978/4108) I found a nice reference that had quite a bit of data, real and simulated, maybe it has something for you?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'm looking more for combustion related information but the temperature data maybe useful to compare once I have built a working model.

Comment: You could get an R/C jet as a working model.  You would not want a homebuilt exploding in class.  Diagrams should suffice.  A field trip to the airport might be fun.

Comment: Funny enough the only groups that share all the data for their engines are model jets. Being models they don't have quite as much of the technical data but still they are open. I found a model jet used for education that has a lot of accompanying data.

https://www.turbinetechnologies.com/educational-lab-products/turbojet-engine-lab

Answer (score 1):

Old data is still data.

Aircraft Emissions Characterization: F101 and F110 Engines
March 1990, Chester SpicerM. W. HoldrenD. L. Smith, et al

1990's report on an engine design that, according to wiki, was the basis for the CFM 56.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235111468_Aircraft_Emissions_Characterization_F101_and_F110_Engines

Has ambient and combustion temperature data, ppm of NOX, NO2, CO, CO2, thrust output, mass flow of both air and fuel. Really the only thing it is missing for a full combustion analysis and ideal jet propulsion analysis is the efficiencies.

I just built the model assuming everything was ideal and needed an HV of 55,000 (which is way above jet fuel) to make it match the data.