# Which type of chevrons is applied on the B787?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, noise, boeing-787, noise-reduction

Which type of chevron nozzle was applied on the B787? I'm really confused about whether if it's sawtooth or sine wave.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking, its neither. Chevrons don't resemble either a [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) or a [sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) in mathematical terms. The closest is that it is a smoothed (modified) saw tooth form.

[image: Chevron]

Image from [compositesworld.com](http://www.compositesworld.com/articles/facc-ag-aerocomposites-powerhouse)

Though the [initial research used a serrated nozzle in saw tooth form](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/19448/9731), the final commercial application differs from it. However, the chevrons are repeatedly noted as having a saw tooth form, [by NASA among others](https://www.nasa.gov/topics/aeronautics/features/bridges_chevron_events.html):

> One of the most recent noise-reducing technologies shepherded through the research process by NASA and now making a difference on commercial jet engines is chevrons.
>
> Chevrons are the sawtooth pattern seen on the trailing edges of some jet engine nozzles.

So, it's a choice between saw tooth and sine wave, its better to go with the former.

GE's [patent for the Chevron](https://www.google.com/patents/US6360528) describes the shape as triangular with qualifications:

> ... each of said chevrons being triangular in configuration
>
> ... said chevrons having a compound concave contour both axially between said bases and apexes and laterally between said trailing edges..

[image: Chevron detail]

Image from [Chevron exhaust nozzle for a gas turbine engine](https://www.google.com/patents/US6360528)