# What type of engine sound suppressors are used in general aviation?

Tags: noise-reduction

Today we were discussing about noise pollution and why aircraft engines considered one of the biggest contributors to producing high intensity sound and I thought are there any ways and/or methods that manufacturers use on engines to control or lower the sound their engines are producing?

Comment: One place to look for info on engine noise reduction is [right here on Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12832/why-does-the-boeing-787-engine-nacelle-exhaust-have-such-an-unusual-shape)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piston engines as used in general aviation typically have a *muffler* (just like cars use) made of welded tubing. But you can't put mufflers on gas turbines because unlike a piston engine, a turbine does not create impulse noise which a muffler can filter out. Instead it creates an intense roaring noise caused by air being turbulently pumped through the engine at very high speed and then shot out the tailpipe with tremendous force.

Also note that a gas turbine engine is stuffed full of axial fan discs with many, many blades on each and when they are set to spinning at tens of thousands of RPM, they generate a siren-like scream that is impractical to suppress in an aircraft.

Note that the propulsive effect of a turbine engine is entirely based on its ability to accelerate extremely large mass flows of air mixed with hot combustion products and blow them out the exhaust. In this case, more thrust means more noise unless you can cleverly surround the hot core exhaust with a blanket of slower-moving bypass air from the fan disc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I may, you would know any thing about a component called the unit mixer? Typically, it is used on a gas turbine engine especially at the exhaust nozzle. I wasn't able to hear it properly when this other guy was mentioning it to a fellow student.

Comment: No, I don't, sorry. -NN

Comment: You describe turbo*jet* engines here but those are obsolete.  Modern high-bypass turbo*fans* develop almost all their thrust from the fan, not the turbine - they don't even bother putting a thrust reverser on the turbine part of thrust.   So there would be no particular loss of thrust from routing turbine output through muffling devices.

Comment: Almost all thrust? not 40-60%? and what muffler technology would you use to filter out 15-20 kilohertz blade noise? as it is, blanketing the core exhaust with the bypass works remarkably well.

Comment: From my understanding the turbo-fan or high-bypass engines are used in general aviation while a pure get is used in the military( example the F-35). In regards to the turbo-fan I have noticed that PW has developed an engine called **the gear turbo-fan engine** to mitigate sound pollution. I saw a picture of these **mixer unit** on the exit nozzle of a jet engine and I was amazed. You might be right this technology may have become obsolete. I understand that the fan is driven by the LP compressor which is connected to the LP turbine and the bypass air contributes about 80% to the thrust.