# What is the meaning of T/O Thrust => TRQ / N1 in a flight log?

Tags: terminology, logging

I work at a software company which builds record-keeping software for aviation.

What is the meaning of `TRQ / N1` in a flight log, under a `T/O Thrust` header? I imagine it refers to *torque* [at N1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14690/what-are-n1-and-n2) (but in my limited experience, I have rarely encountered instantaneous torque as a relevant measure in aviation so I'm suspicious).

What is the meaning of `TRQ / N1`? Is this, like `N1`, expressed as a percentage?

(Indeed, we have a close relationship with out clients and can ask them, but answers sometimes take time and I prefer to be proactive and know more than the bare minimum.)

Comment: @Federico That in itself is useful information.  I assumed these were industry-standard terminology. I edited to add more context if it helps.

Comment: Torque is used extensively as a power setting and limiting indication in turboprop applications.

Comment: @JonathanWalters Thank you for noting that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jet engines use N1, [EPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_pressure_ratio), or lately (Airbus A350) [Thrust %](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33799/14897) values for takeoff power.

[Turboprop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turboprop) aircraft use torque. So it's either N1 **or** torque for your software depending on which aircraft is used for the flight.

Comment: Indeed, the fleet consists entirely of turboprop aircraft. Thank you!