# What are the main differences between scimitar and regular propellers?

Tags: propeller

I am looking to know the main differences between scimitar and regular propellers. Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: [Closely related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27701/62)

Comment: If you're talking about a scimitar on a Cirrus or Bonanza there is little if any benefit other than just looking cool.  The turboprop market typically doesn't rely on "cool" as a marketing technique (it helps though) so there must be some advantage for high powered aircraft.  High powered in this case means C130 or A400.  I would also like a technical description.  Maybe Peter K will be along soon with a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Primarily the curved sweep of the blade's leading edge, allowing for better efficiency at higher engine speeds.

Comment: If I remember correctly, doesn't the sweep of the blade allow it to turn faster because it keeps the tips from going supersonic at the higher rotation?

Answer (score 1):

The scimitar's swept back design results in less drag. On top of that it lets you increase the overall length of the propeller's airfoil without lengthening the diameter of the propeller. And since lengthening the propeller's diameter results in the tip of the blade traveling at a higher mach, the scimitar gives you all the benefits of a longer airfoil with none of the noise or drag penalties associated with a transonic propeller tip.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You may be right, but can you give some more detailed explanation and maybe some links? It would be great to know *why* a scimitar prop would have less drag.

Comment: Um, sorry? That was about as much as an explanation as Carlo gave so I just followed suit.