# What are these holes in the engine inlet?

Tags: jet-engine, feature-identification

In the next picture can be seen within the housing, near the inlet:

[image: Front view of turbofan engine]
[image: Closeup of inlet section]
[image]

Comment: Are those definitely holes and not rivets? Also what are "aerodynamic takes"?

Comment: Sorry, I 'm Spanish and my English is pretty bad. " aerodynamic Takes" is the literal English translation of " toma aerodinámica" in Spanish , which is what you call in English " inlet" .

Comment: Is there any way you can put a circle or an arrow on the photoindicating specifically what you're referring to?

Comment: It is done. Now that I look, yes they could be rivets...

Comment: My first reaction is rivets, comparing them to the rivets on the seam to the right. The circled ones do look a bit randomly spaced for rivets, though. I'm wondering if it might be the textured surface of the acoustic liner. Hopefully someone that knows for sure will answer.

Comment: [Rivets doesn't appear always evenly spaced](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Rolls_royce_engine_on_boeing_757-300.JPG) or aligned.

Comment: It is very possible that they're holes too. For example in CF34-10E5 engine the nacelle inlet is full of small holes. Unfortunately I have no idea what they are there for.

Comment: Could serve to absorb the boundary layer?

Comment: @Sami the many small holes further downstream in the inlet serve to [reduce the noise](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11884/1696).

Comment: My eye immediately went to the 6 dark spots on the spinner, which could be holes, and thought "That's a good question!". I guess I was looking at the wrong holes.

Comment: The holes on the spinner are actually for access to the bolts that hold the tip of the spinner in place. You remove that plate to get inside the spinner.

Comment: Here's a picture of how the spinner is attached .http://imgur.com/a/lWLHq

Comment: the circled points are definitelly rivets, they are pretty smooth and flush with the inlet. No ideea about small holes for noise, but the IAE engines we use have no such holes before the fan blades

Comment: They look like rivets to me.

Answer (score 8):

These are "[acoustic liners](https://www.win.tue.nl/ceas-asc/Workshop15/CEAS-ASC_XNoise-EV_K1_Kempton.pdf)"; they allow the sound waves to get "trapped" in the holes and make the engine quieter. Sometimes chunks tear loose and they're repaired with what amounts to Bondo.

Comment: So it's like a silencer for jet engine hah, pretty cool

Answer (score -4):

This is anti-ice system. Hot air is blown in this holes and ice/snow not settle in jet engine.

Comment: Welcome. Can you provide a reference to this?

Comment: No. The silver cowling is heated for anti-icing. These holes aren't for heating, but as @fooot commented above, for noise reduction.

Comment: This answer is wrong.

Answer (score -5):

The holes you are referring to are a part of the engine-inlet anti-icing system. These holes prevent ice accumulation around the engine inlets. Without them, the engines may ingest ice and will also encounter airflow problems. Engines require laminar airflow in order to operate efficiently.

[image]

Comment: Respectfully, your answer is incorrect.