# Is this a 737-800 or 737 MAX 8?

Tags: aircraft-identification, boeing-737

[image]

Is this a 737-800 or 737 MAX 8?

Answer (score 11):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_MAX):

> The MAX is re-engined with more efficient CFM International LEAP-1B powerplants, aerodynamic improvements (most notably split-tip winglets), and airframe modifications.

Checking what the new features are allow for easier identification. The photo you have lacks the [split-tip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingtip_device#Split-tip) wingtip device. And when the viewing angle is tricky, like the one below, the [engine chevrons](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38275/14897) would be another thing to look for (only available on the MAX series).

[image]
([planespotters.net](https://www.planespotters.net/photo/811366/a6-max-flydubai-boeing-737-8-max))

Comment: One other way to tell an NG from a MAX by the engines: all Classic and NG 737s have the famous ["hamster-pouch" intakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737#Engines), while the 737 MAX series have bog-standard circular intakes.  Also, 737NGs [can also have split-tip winglets, although of a slightly different "split-scimitar" design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737#Winglets).

Answer (score 6):

The tail number in the photo looks to be [A6-FEA](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/Boeing/737/A6-FEA-flydubai/kZWDIpZn), which is a 737-800. (The A6-F part is harder to make out, but it's used by [flydubai's entire fleet](https://www.planespotters.net/airline/flydubai).)

I would suggest using the highest resolution photo available and zooming in, as your aircraft ID questions all seem to have visible tail numbers, though some are hard to make out once they've been scaled by the Stack Exchange uploader.