# Is the 737-800 a different plane from the 737 MAX 8?

Tags: boeing-737, boeing

I am flying on March 16 from Barbados to Toronto on a Westjet Boeing 737-800 also referred to as an aircraft type 73H on my ticket. Is this a different plane from the Boeing 737 MAX 8, grounded by several countries?

Answer (score 14):

They are different, yes. The 73H is not the Max 8. The 73H is an [-800 with winglets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation#737-800). The -800 has been in service since 1998, with 4,991 deliveries as of February 28, 2019.

See here: [What is the difference between Boeing 73G, 73H and 737?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14034/14897)

> 73H - Boeing 737-800 with winglets (8th letter of the alphabet)

The Max 8's [IATA code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ICAO_aircraft_type_designators) you'd find on a ticket is **7M8.**

---

For visual identification, see: [Is this a 737-800 or 737 MAX 8?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/48929/is-this-a-737-800-or-737-max-8/48932#48932)