# How did the Blackops 'quiet one' helicopter muffler work?

Tags: helicopter, turbine, noise-reduction

Back in the Vietnam War era, special ops needed a quiet means of [inserting soldiers behind enemy lines](https://www.airspacemag.com/military-aviation/air-americas-black-helicopter-24960500/) to install eavesdropping equipment. They modified a Hughes 500 to do the job. One of the things done was the addition of a muffler to the jet exhaust. How did it work? It looks very different from the [lobes and serrations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38275/what-noise-reduction-measures-were-taken-in-the-time-between-hush-kits-and-chevr) used to quiet the cores and fan exhaust in turbofan engines.

> "I'd stand on the [landing pad] and try to figure out the first time I could hear it and which direction it was coming from. I couldn't place it until it was one or two hundred yards away."

With all recent the interest in municipal vertical flight this might be useful in modern helicopters as they are much more intrusive than this.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  Never heard of such a thing!

Comment: Basically a large automotive-type muffler. They don't need thrust from it and probably don't mind a small drop in efficiency due to the priorities of the mission. A commercial aircraft is more concerned with performance and fuel efficiency.

Comment: @MaxPower Do you have knowledge of its construction or is this opinion?